# Getting corrupted mp3 after downloading file using requests in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, mp3, urllib

I am trying to download mp3 file using `requests` in Python

example url - https://example.net/song.mp3

```
r = requests.get(downnloadLink)

with open(r"C:\Users\shrey\Desktop\test.mp3", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
    print("Downloaded!")
```

the file is getting downloaded but I couldn't play it and getting this error
[image]

Seems like it's not getting downloaded in proper format

Comment: Download the file with browser then compare its hash with the one you downloaded with the script. Check if they are the same

Answer (score 1):

I think you're downloading the html content. You should check if what you have downloaded is 'mp3'. So first download the file with a normal browser, then compare that with the file downloaded with your script. You can just compare their hashes to see if they are the same.

But if what you want is just a script to download mp3, you can use the following script.

```py
import requests
url = "URL FOR THE MUSIC FILE"

def DownloadFile(url):
    local_filename = 'test.mp3'
    r = requests.get(url)
    with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
            if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)
    return None

DownloadFile(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that Windows sort of skips a step when downloading a .mp3 file with Python. This isn't something that happens with Linux however.

To download .mp3 files in Linux you need to try to open the file in binary file mode. open(mp3Name, "wb") You're probably getting line ending translations.

The file is binary, yes. It's the mode that wasn't. When a file is opened, it can be set to read as a text file (this is default). When it does this, it will convert line endings to match the platform. On Windows, line ends are \r\n In most other places it's either \r or \n. This change messes up the data stream